# Akka using UDP - How to test?

Tags: java, io, udp, akka

It's my first day with Akka and a have to make somes tests with UDP. I'm using exactaly [this code](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.0/java/io-udp.html), in Java, without any personal changes, but I don't know how to test it.

How can i make test with this code?

Comment: If you don't know how to test it, how are we supposed to know? What are you trying to test exactly?

Comment: Sorry, is that why I tried to make a Main class to test it, with ActorSystem, ActorRef, etc, but it seems that don't work. I don't know for example wich Manager i have to pass on Server parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and create a listner and sender actors and everything works fine.